# Somehow display C++ application using double-click on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I'm totally new to Ubuntu and C++. Anyway, I have PHP experience.

I just created very simple application...

```
#include <iostream>



int main() {

    std::cout << "Hello, world!";


    return false;

}
```

Then compiled it....

```
g++ hello-world.cpp -o hello-world
```

But I can't open it with double-click on it, like I did on Windows 7. Only way to get that text printed is to do command...

```
./hello-world
```

Is it possible to open compiled file using simple double-click and then get that text somehow printed?

Comment: Is it that you want the shell output to log into a file and print it?

Comment: Probably. I'm really newb. In Windows 7 I did like this: compile .cpp file, get .exe file, run it simply using double-click, get text from it in the Console.

Comment: This probably goes over on Ask Ubuntu or Unix and Linux

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code.  Try to add a cin<< to the end and see if the console window stays up.  Other wise this is a window manger configuration thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program you wrote is a console application. In most Linux GUIs, by default if you open a console program from the GUI, the console output will not be displayed. You can either configure the GUI to open a terminal, or you can manually open a terminal and run it yourself.

When doing development, I highly recommend manually running the program - with using the GUI's automatic terminal window opening mode, the terminal will close as soon as the program terminates; so if the program crashes, the message will be lost. Manually opening a terminal ensures it sticks around after termination, so you can read the program's last messages before terminating.